# In linear programming, How can I give a value to a binary variable y depending on whether a continuous variable is 0 (y = 0) or positive (y = 1)?

Tags: python, linear-programming

I have a binary variable `y` and a continuos variable `x`, and I would like to implement in linear programming (Python mip) the next condition:

```
if x > 0:
   y = 1
else:
   y = 0
```

I have tried the following:

```
self.model.add_constr(y >= 0, name=f"Lin 2.1")
self.model.add_constr(y * 10000000 >= x, name=f"Lin 2.2")
self.model.add_constr(y <= x * 10000000, name=f"Lin 2.2")
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
x >= 0.001 - M(1-y)
x <= 0     + My
y ∈ {0,1}
```

where M is a large enough constant (carefully chosen).

Comment: What value for M could be correct? Would it suffice to be greater than the maximum value of x?

Comment: Let's see if we can do some basic high school math. If x ∈ [L,U] where L < 0 then the first M can be 0.001-L. The second M can be U.